# HTML Code to display UIAlertView on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uialertview

I've gone to different websites on my iPhone that will pop up a UIAlertView when it loads.  How is this accomplished?  I want to put some code on my page to pop up a UIAlertView when viewed on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bridecall from the js to native code to trigger the UIAlertView..